# Open mat-sidenav from end position with Mini icon variant

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-sidenav

I am working with angular 7 and angular material.
I tried to set `<mat-sidenav>` with Mini icon variant in `position="end"`
I want that when I click to open the side nav all the icon remain in their place
like what happening in position "start" + my text in Hebrew will be after the icon like English text in a start position.
see [Demo end position](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4gmby-m7okqq?file=app%2Fsidenav-autosize-example.html)

any help will be blessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, just added a few things to better handle the icon container since it was getting pushed to the right side.

These are the two changes I made

```
.icon-container {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

<mat-list-item>
    <p  matLine *ngIf="isExpanded">בדיקה</p>
    <div class="icon-container">
      <mat-icon mat-list-icon>home</mat-icon>
    </div>
</mat-list-item>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4gmby-ydh9sf

Comment: looks perfect! thank you,
I tried to do it to the icons of the open and close nav but it didn't help.
what can I do?

Comment: I'm actually trying to get those fixed as well right now :) I'll let you know as soon as I get them aligned as well

Comment: Don't really get what you mean, can you show a demo?

Comment: I tried to split the code into a components and add a toolbar.
but it's not working as well as before that all the code in the same .ts file 
see [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4gmby-dzdxny)
@IvanS95

Comment: What happens is that Angular has something called "ViewEncapsulation", this makes styles scoped only to its component, that way you can define classes and styles to specific components without those styles affecting other elements in the page; you can turn this off but it s not recommended; anyways, what happened now is that you didn't move the styles I created to the css file of the new component you made, so the styles I used were not affecting the component.

Comment: You can read more about it here https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-scope

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
yes, I know that. I just forgot to move it in the demo.
But if you can see after this change is still not working as well.
If you take a closer look on the code of the toolbar you see that in the right corner should be a title - "check" but it still disappeared by the navbar even though I encapsulate the CSS to his current component

Comment: @EzriY the reason for that is that because of how you have built the whole structure the navbar sits on top of the remaining components, you either have to change the positioning of the sidebar o add a `margin-right` or `padding` to compensate for that space